# MAUI decode Base64 webservice responses fails with error, and yet the string seems to be valid

Tags: web-services, base64, decode, maui

I am really-really confused now.

I am calling in Net Maui a webservice, like this:

```
internal static bool GetTypeConfigurations(string smartRequestUrl, string serviceToken, out DataTable? dt)
        {
            bool okay = true;
            dt = null;

            try
            {
                string? response = smartRequestUrl
                    .AppendPathSegment("MyRequest")
                    .AppendPathSegment("GetTypeConfigurations")
                    .WithTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15))
                    .WithOAuthBearerToken(serviceToken)
                    .GetStringAsync()
                    .Result.Trim();

                dt = Functions.ConvertFromBase64String<DataTable>(response);
                okay = (dt != null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                okay = false;
                ErrorHandling.HandleError(ex);
            }

            return okay;
        }
```

See ? A very simple function (I am using Flurl). Then I have

```
internal static T? ConvertFromBase64String<T>(string content) where T : class
        {
            byte[]? bytes = null;

            try
            {
                if (content == null)
                    return null;

                bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(content);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorHandling.HandleError(ex);
            }

            return (T)DecompressNone(bytes);
        }

        private static byte[]? CompressNone(object obj)
        {
            byte[]? serializedObj = null;

            try
            {
                using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                binaryFormatter.Serialize(ms, obj);

                WSEBugWorkAroundSerialization(ms);

                serializedObj = ms.ToArray();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorHandling.HandleError(ex);
            }

            return serializedObj;
        }
```

From GetTypeConfigurations() I get back a response like

AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAE5TeXN0ZW0uRGF0YSwgVmVyc2lvbj00LjAuMC4wLCBDdWx0dXJlPW5ldXRyYWwsIFB1YmxpY0tleVRva2VuPWI3N2E1YzU2MT............

When I try to call my ConvertFromBase64String() function, on the line

```
bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(content);
```

I get the error

**The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.**

Even if I break on the line

```
dt = Functions.ConvertFromBase64String<DataTable>(response);
```

and I inspect the value of response without executing my Decode functions, I still get the same message even in Visual Studio:

[image]

And yet, in
https://www.base64decode.org/
I can decode my response and get this:
[image]

Why is this happening ? Why can I not decode the response in visual studio, but the website above can ? What's wrong with my "response" variable ?

Thank you.
Alex

Comment: Does it end with ==?

Comment: Does `content.Length` exactly equal the length that the web server has? Is it a multiple of 4? If either of these are not true, then maybe a character encoding difference between server and client code.

Comment: Hello. Yes, it ended with ==.

Comment: I have discovered that calling it like this works: 

string? response = smartRequestUrl
                    .AppendPathSegment("Request")
                    .AppendPathSegment("GetRequests")
                    .SetQueryParams(new
                    {
                        StartDate = string.Empty,
                        EndDate = string.Empty,
                    })
                    .WithTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15))
                    .WithOAuthBearerToken(serviceToken)
                    .GetStringAsync()
                    .Result.Trim('\0').Trim('"');